ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 38; 2 is required
Using FastAPI and SQLAlchemy and I'm completely stuck here. I don't even understand the error message. Been googling for a few days, read similar questions, but haven't found a solution that works.
In this code:
def get_events_by_month(db: Session, month: int):    
    sq = db.query(models.Events.title, models.Events.start, over(func.row_number(), partition_by=models.Events.start).label('rn')).subquery()
    print(sq)
    q = db.query(sq.c.title, sq.c.start).where(sq.c.rn <= 3).all()
    print(q)
    return q

print(sq) prints the correct query
print(q) prints the desired data, as a list of tuples
return q gives the following error:
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 322, in jsonable_encoder
    data = dict(obj)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 38; 2 is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 327, in jsonable_encoder
    data = vars(obj)
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 411, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 69, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1054, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 123, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 186, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 164, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 83, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(self.app, conn)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 758, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 778, in app
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 299, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 79, in app
    await wrap_app_handling_exceptions(app, request)(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 64, in wrapped_app
    raise exc
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 53, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 74, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 296, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 180, in serialize_response
    return jsonable_encoder(response_content)
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 301, in jsonable_encoder
    jsonable_encoder(
  File "/home/mortyar/Desktop/coding projects/calendar-next14-fastapi/backend/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/encoders.py", line 330, in jsonable_encoder
    raise ValueError(errors) from e
ValueError: [ValueError('dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 38; 2 is required'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]

I've seen some similar questions, but none of them had a solution that I could use.
I tried converting the tuple to a dict, but that didn't work (I probably did it wrong, though)
I don't know what else to do.
edited to add:
Endpoint, in main.py:
@app.get("/events/{month}")
def get_events_by_month(month: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.get_events_by_month(db, month)

I've tried it both with and without a response model, which would be:
class EventsBase(BaseModel):
    title: Optional[str]
    start: Optional[date]

And from the models file:
class Events(Base):
    __tablename__ = "events"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("start", "url", name="event"),)

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = Column((VARCHAR(300)))
    start = Column(DATE, index=True, nullable=False)
    end = Column(DATE)
    registry = Column(VARCHAR(50), index=True)
    city = Column(VARCHAR(50))
    location = Column(VARCHAR(10), index=True)
    discipline = Column(VARCHAR(50), index=True)
    url = Column(VARCHAR(500), nullable=False)


The error is occuring in FastAPI, not in the function you've included. Please include the full API endpoint code.

You're returning something that can't be automagically serialized to JSON - so the endpoint information will be useful. Also be aware that SQLAlchemy objects might not be interpretable directly as JSON encodable.

Added more code.

You'll need to add a pydantic response model @app.get("/events/{month}", response_model=List[EventsBase]) (that matches what you want to return, and add model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True) for it to read the values from attributes instead of keys (which is what SQLAlchemy exposes): https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.7/api/base_model/#pydantic.BaseModel.model_config

@MatsLindh thank you! I'd tried the response model and config previously without success, but hadn't cast it to List. That solved it.
